Using cordinate and swept function at creo
How to draw cable from point a to point b on a messive assemble part at creo parametric? I having difficulty to understand the coordinate and swept feature at creo.
Please give a step by step guidelines to help me as I am struggling to adjust the coordinate x,y,z for sweeping direction.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

hi Mario thanks for the respond, my working drawing is sole proprietor. Appreciate if you can show screenshot with pictures step by step. how to create datum or coordinate and show me the sweep function maybe a PCB with a with jumper wire from location point a to  b.
